# Kafka Avro Serializer and deserializer exception. Avro supported types

Tags: java, serialization, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I am seeing following error

```
exception Unsupported Avro type. Supported types are null, Boolean, Integer, Long, Float, Double, String, byte[] and IndexedRecord
```

my kafka producer props are

```
Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, KafkaConstants.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, 1000);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroSerializer.class.getName());
    props.put("schema.registry.url", "http://localhost:8081");
    props.put("value.converter.schema.registry.url", "http://localhost:8081");
    props.put("producer.type", "sync");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, KafkaConstants.CLIENT_ID);

    Producer<String, TweetInfoDto> producer = new KafkaProducer(props);
```

and my kafka consumer props are

```
Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, KafkaConstants.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "twitterCrawler");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, KafkaConstants.CLIENT_ID);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    props.put("schema.registry.url", "http://localhost:8081");
    props.put("value.converter.schema.registry.url", "http://localhost:8081");

    Consumer<String, TweetInfoDto> consumer = new KafkaConsumer(props);
```

not sure what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Well, is `TweetInfoDto` an `IndexedRecord` such as `SpecificAvroRecord`?

Comment: Also, `value.converter` is for Connect API, not Producer/Consumer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TweetInfoDto` cannot be a plain Java object that you have defined yourself.

It ideally should be created from an Avro schema via the [Avro Maven Plugin](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/gettingstartedjava.html), for example.

Please refer to the [Schema Registry Tutorial](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/schema_registry_tutorial.html) for all the steps including defining an AVSC, and generating a Java class for it.

[Tutorial sample code here](https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/tree/5.0.1-post/clients/avro)

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to what cricket_007 has mentioned, could consider using
[avro tools - Serializing and deserializing with code generation](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/gettingstartedjava.html)

Comment: That is what the `avro-maven-plugin` uses in the tutorial